# Can I read NFC NDEF messages multiple times on iOS?

Tags: ios, nfc, ndef

I want to do the following:

1. Hold iPhone in front of my device's NFC tag
2. Read the tag's NDEF messages

   - After reading, the tag's NDEF messages will be overwritten by my device (*not* by the iPhone). Go to 2.
   - After reading a "no more data" message, stop reading and go to 3.
3. Finish

Is it possible to do this with [CoreNFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) without having to move the iPhone back and forth to recognize the "new" NFC tag again?

Comment: Thanks to iOS 13, I have no longer go the NDEF way. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your setup consists of
- An NFC Tag emulated by your device (not necessarily an iPhone)
- iPhone acting as a reader
- my device acting as a writer

Sequence of operations
1) Device is in CE mode with NDEF content
2) Device is proximated to iPhone which then reads the tag
3) Device re-writes the tag with a fresh NDEF message
4) iPhone reads the tag
5) Steps 3 and 4 repeat until step 3 is replaced with 'erase tag'

Answers to your query:
First of all, you need a synchronization mechanism between iPhone and your device to serialise step 3 and 4.
Secondly, after reading is complete iPhone needs to deselect the card so that it can select it after the new data is written. Usually, this will not be a standard behavior of iPhone since it expects the tag to move away and be brought back. So, you need to tweak iPhone.

Note: Device for subsequent discussions can be considered as an MCU connected to an N-TAG. In this case, its not in CE-mode, but is a physical Tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The NFC chip has an output that triggers an interrupt after reading a message. Thanks to iOS 13's opening of the NFC interface, I no longer need to go this way so that reading from and writing to the chip's SRAM is now possible for data transfer.

Comment: Glad to know. Can you please share the relevant iOS13's documentation explaining this?

Comment: Sure. Just have a look at the Core NFC documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc

Comment: It will help if you can pin point to the page that describes the interrupt mechanism for reading NDEF messages. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Another doc Section 4.2 of the App Note "How to use the NTAG I²C plus for bidirectional
communication" https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11579.pdf describes the mechanism involved.